# Gallstones: risks of leaving untreated? Effective non-surgical treatments?

Tags: health-education, natural-remedy, gallstone

I have done quite a bit of research about natural remedies to treat gallstones and have come to this site looking to expand my research.  One source said that stones cannot get smaller and gallbladder removal is the only solution.  But wouldn't NOT having a gallbladder lead to health problems?

Is there evidence for effective *non-surgical* treatment options for gallstones - especially natural remedies?

Or are there even any health risks to just leaving it untreated?

I have come to this site to expand my research. I feel hopeful with the credibility of members and admins in passing on reliable information.
Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Welcome @user11199!  It is a good question but there are a few issues.  One, it's a request for medical advice; [this explains why we cannot give that here.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor?cb=1).  This can be fixed by removing ALL clinical history and asking the fundamental pathophysiology question.  (2) It is very broad with multiple questions, making it dificult to answer.  I can offer to edit it for you, and you can revert it if you dislike it.

Comment: I will remove my downvote and close vote if you can adjust the question accordingly!

Comment: Hi DoctorWhom I am happy for you to edit it. Thank you very much for offering. Have a happy weekend!

Comment: @DoctorWhom the OP is happy for you to edit the question

Comment: Please compare how I changed your question to better fit site standards.  It may still be a bit broad but is much better than before.  Hope this was helpful!

Comment: @DoctorWhom hello, thank you very much for editing the question for me.